# How to get the playlist of currently playing item using systemMusicPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mpmediaplayercontroller

I'm currently building a music app and I want to get the playlist of the currently playing item (in Apple Music).

I don't mean I want to use a MPMediaPickerController, because I only want to get the media items of the current playlist.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't start the playlist yourself, it's not possible to retrieve what items are coming up next.

You can get the information for the currently playing song by getting the nowPlayingItem from the player, but any queue related APIs are write-only.

Answer (score 2):

**MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer**

import MediaPlayer

```
let audioInfo = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()
let audioName = audioPath.lastPathComponent!.stringByDeletingPathExtension
audioInfo.nowPlayingInfo = [ MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: audioName, MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:"artistName"]
```

Documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/